# exchange 2010 email forward

Tags: exchange-2010, mail-forwarding

I have an Exchange 2010 server with an AD account and mailbox which I wish to forward all the email to external non domain email address (gmail for example).

When I go to forwarding options in the account properties via EMC, I am able to select ONLY Active Directory users.

How can I force the recipient scope to allow me to forward to any email address?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create mail contact. [Step by step instructions](http://exchangepedia.com/2008/02/how-to-forward-mail-to-an-external-email-address.html).

For the sake of full answer here's a cut-and-paste from the liink:

> 1. Create a MailContact using the EMC:
>
>    - Expand Recipeint Configuration | Mail Contact
>    - In the Action pane, click New Mail Contact
>    - To create a new Contact object, leave the default (New Contact)
>        selected | click Next
>    - Type First name, Last name
>    - Click Edit to add the external email address
>    - Click New to complete creation of new MailContact
> 2. Forward mail for a recipient to the MailContact
>
> Now that we have a MailContact created for the external recipient’s
>   email address, we can forward mail for the Exchange recipient to the
>   MailContact. To configure mail forwarding using the EMC:
>
> - Expand Recipeint Configuration | Mailbox | select mailbox |
>     properties | Mail Flow Settings tab | Delivery Options
> - Under Forwarding address, select Forward to
> - Click Browse to select the MailContact

Comment: I thank you very much for your help. following the steps has provided a solution for my issue. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a contact in Active Directory that contains the email address you want to forward to. Then add a forwarder to that contact object.

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to create a contact actually. Just open ADSIEdit, navigate to the mailbox that you want to forward mail for and select Properties. Then find the targetAddress property and edit it. Put the remote email address in the below format and you're good.

SMTP:user@gmail.com

Comment: -1 because you don't "just open ADSI Edit". You generally use that tool when something is *seriously* wrong, it's not a general purpose editor like ADUC is.